# Java: Null Pointer Deque Iterator

Tags: java, exception, iterator

I've been assigned to write a class that takes a mathematical expression in infix notation and turns that expression into an equivalent one in postfix notation. That part I've already completed.

I was also assigned to write an iterator that would let client code iterate over the tokens of the postfix expression.

So, the code I have for my iterator so far is:

```
class PostfixIterator implements Iterator<String> { //this is line 117

private Deque<String> postfix;

public PostfixIterator(Deque<String> postfix) {
    this.postfix = postfix;
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    return postfix.isEmpty();
}

public String next() {
    return postfix.pop(); //this is line 130
}

}
```

When I try to create an instance of my iterator and call one of the methods, I get a null pointer exception and I can't figure out why.

This is what my main looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    InfixToPostfix a = new InfixToPostfix("(123)^45+6*7/89");
    Iterator itr = a.iterator();
    System.out.println(itr.next());

}
```

According to my compiler, return postfix.pop() is evaluating to null. I'm not sure why though.

So, could someone help me get this working and possibly explain why what I have now doesn't work?

Thanks

Here is my entire InfixToPost fix class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class InfixToPostfix{

    private Deque<String> postfix;

    public InfixToPostfix(String infix){

        Deque<String> postfix = new LinkedList<String>();
        Deque<String> infixQ = new LinkedList<String>();

        //tokenize the user input
        int i = 0;
        char ch;
        infix = infix.replaceAll("\\s","");//make sure there is no whitespace
         while(i < infix.length()){
             ch = infix.charAt(i);

             if(ch == '(' || ch == ')'|| ch == '+'|| ch == '-' 
                     || ch == '/' || ch == '%'|| ch == '*' 
                     || ch == '^'){
                 String s =ch+"";
                 infixQ.add(s);
                 i++;
             }
             else if (Character.isDigit(ch)){
                 String s ="";
                 int j = i;
                 char c = infix.charAt(j);
                 while(j <= infix.length()-1 && //accumulate the digits in that number
                       Character.isDigit(c = infix.charAt(j))){
                     s = s + c;
                     j++;
                 }
                 infixQ.add(s);
                 i=j;
             }
             else if (Character.isLetter(ch)){
                 String s ="";
                 int j = i;
                 char c = infix.charAt(j);
                 while(j <= infix.length()-1 && //accumulate the lettes in that variable
                       Character.isLetter(c = infix.charAt(j))){
                     s = s + c;
                     j++;
                 }
                 infixQ.add(s);
                 i=j;
             }
        }
        System.out.println(infixQ);

        //start shunting-yard
        Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<String>();
        Iterator<String> itr = infixQ.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            String s = itr.next();

            //if token is number or a variable, put it on the output queue
            if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)) 
               || Character.isLetter(s.charAt(0))){
                postfix.add(s);
            }
           if(s.equals("(")){
                stack.push(s);
            }
            if(s.equals(")")){
                while((!stack.isEmpty())&&(!stack.peek().equals("("))){
                    postfix.add(stack.pop());
                }
                stack.pop();
            }
            if(s.equals("+") || s.equals("-")){
                while((!stack.isEmpty()) && (stack.peek().equals("+") 
                     || stack.peek().equals("-")
                     || stack.peek().equals("*") || stack.peek().equals("/")
                     || stack.peek().equals("^"))){
                     postfix.add(stack.pop());

                }
                stack.push(s);
            }
            if(s.equals("*") || s.equals("/") || s.equals("%")){
                if(!stack.isEmpty()){
                    while((!stack.isEmpty())&&(stack.peek().equals("*") 
                          || stack.peek().equals("/") 
                          || stack.peek().equals("%")
                          || stack.peek().equals("^"))){
                        postfix.add(stack.pop());            
                    }
                }
                stack.push(s);
            }
            if(s.equals("^")){
                stack.push(s);
            }       
        }
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            postfix.add(stack.pop());
        }
        System.out.println(stack.isEmpty());
        System.out.println(postfix);        
    }

    public Iterator<String> iterator(){
        return new PostfixIterator(postfix);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        InfixToPostfix a = new InfixToPostfix("(123)^45+6*7/89");
        Iterator itr = a.iterator();
        System.out.println(itr.next()); // this is line 112

    }
    }
```

I'm positive its poorly written. I just need it to work so I can turn it in, though.

And here is my stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at PostfixIterator.next(InfixToPostfix.java:130)
at PostfixIterator.next(InfixToPostfix.java:117)
at InfixToPostfix.main(InfixToPostfix.java:112)
```

Comment: where is your InfixToPostfix  class? I do not get how PostfixIterator  is gonna iterate over InfixToPostfix?!!! you need to post up more info

Comment: If postfix.pop() is returning null then, it will be printed as null, just because "itr" itself is null the exception occurs. Please verify this.

Comment: can you post your InfixToPostfix class? does a.iterator(); return your PostfixIterator class properly?

Comment: now you need to post up your **stack trace** plz

Comment: Posted my stack trace.

Comment: can you tell us where those lines that your stack trace indicated in your code?

Comment: @KickButtowski Okay, I've inserted comments that indicate which lines those are.

Comment: @HadenBarrow you never instantiate your postfix data field in PostfixIterator class? Deque is interface which implementation you wanna try?

Comment: @KickButtowski Don't I instantiate it inside the constructor when I declare Deque<String> postfix = new LinkedList<String>(); ?

Answer (score 4):

You problem is about scoping of your data field `postfix`

This is what you have :

```
public class InfixToPostfix{

    private Deque<String> postfix; <-- this is data field 

    public InfixToPostfix(String infix){

        Deque<String> postfix = new LinkedList<String>();
                         ^
                         |   
you declared that reference here again which shadows the data field. 
postfix is just visible in constructor and out of here your data field
is still pointing to null value.
```

change it to

```
postfix = new LinkedList<String>();
```

as a result you will instantiate the postfix and when you want to access it , it will never be `null` because you instantiated the data field `postfix`.

Some Suggestions:

1. you can use **diamond inference** since `Java 7`

For example:

```
 List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

can be written

```
  List<String> myList = new ArrayList< >();
                                      ^
                                      |
```

and if you can choose different name for your iterator function in below code is better because you may confuse whoever reads your code

```
public Iterator<String> iterator(){
        return new PostfixIterator(postfix);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you declare variable "postfix" twice, you should use the class variable "postfix" only.

```
public class InfixToPostfix{

   private Deque<String> postfix;

   public InfixToPostfix(String infix){

        postfix = new LinkedList<String>();
        // Code here
   }
}
```